# How to create a multidimensional array, whose dimension is based on a variable in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic

Basically, I want to be able to type in the dimension n in the terminal and create the corresponding n-D array.

Right now I'm only able to create a one dimensional array with the size of the corresponding n-D array.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, do you want to create a variable whose number of dimensions is variable? Does that make sense? What is your use case?

Comment: If you want to implement an array with a variable number of dimensions, you must create your own routines to support that such as, at least: a routine to allocate the required storage and initialize data structures used to help the implementation and a routine that accepts information about the element to be accessed (perhaps as a pointer to a list or array of indices), calculates the location of that element, and returns a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, the number of dimensions of an array is part of the type, so it needs to be known at compile time. You can do some simple math, to map what you want to a 1d array.

Example:

Let dimensions = 3

- w: 4
- h: 8
- d: 16

Code:

```
int* data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * w * h * d);
int x = access(1,2,3);  //it will map to location: 1 + 2 * (4) + 3 * (4 * 8)
free(data);


int access(int x, int y, int z){
   return data[x + y * (w) + z * (h * w)];
}
```

A general implementation might look like this

```
int numDimensions;
printf("Enter number of dimensions:");
scanf("%d", &numDimensions);
int* dimensionSizes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numDimensions);

//Read each dimension's size
int totalElements = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < numDimensions; ++i){
    printf("Enter size for dimension %d:", i);
    scanf("%d", &dimensionSizes[i]);
    totalElements *= dimensionSizes[i];
}

//allocate 1d array
int* data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * totalElements);

//Read the coordinates you want to store data to
int* position = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numDimensions);
for(int i = 0; i < numDimensions; ++i){
    printf("Enter location in dimension %d:", i);
    scanf("%d", &position[i]);
}

//Read the value you want to store
int value;
printf("Enter value for that position:");
scanf("%d", &value);

//Write the data to the calculated 1d location
data[to1d(position, dimensionSizes, numDimensions)] = value;

int to1d(int* position, int* dimensionSizes, int numDimensions){
    int multiplier = 1;
    int position1d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numDimensions; ++i){
        position1d = position1d + position[i] * multiplier;
        multiplier = multiplier * dimensionSizes[i];
    }
    return position1d;
}
```

Comment: sorry, OP says they want C, hence I remove the C++ tag

Comment: btw C does not have references afaik and in C++ `malloc` should be  matched with `free`, not `delete` (or rather `new` with `delete` or even better no `new` and no `delete`)

Comment: The one-dimensional array is a good idea, but `int access(int x, int y, int z)` says this still needs to be known at compile time. Perhaps a variadic function? But the same applies. An array of indices as suggested by @EricPostpischil makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of the array at runtime using VLA. Variable-length
arrays are part of C99. So this will only work with C99 or up. Although C11 has VLA as an option, all major compilers support it.

Lets say you want the user to input the size of a 2D array from the  terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   unsigned int row1, col1;

   printf("%s", "Enter number of rows and columns in a 2-D array: ");
   int row1, col1; // number of rows and columns in a 2-D array
   scanf("%u %u", &row1, &col1);

   int array2D[row1][col1]; // declare 2-D variable-length array

}
```

array2d is a 2d array declared at run time. Then just write code below to use it.

In early versions of C `sizeof` was always a compile-time operation, but when applied to a VLA, `sizeof` operates at runtime. Will print the number of bytes in a VLA:

Comment: Adding to this, you can use dynamic allocation in order to avoid potential stack size issues,   `int (*x)[col1] = malloc(row1 * sizeof *x);`.  And of course it would be smart to validate that `scanf` succeeded and the values are greater than zero before going on to declare the array.

Comment: @M.M I changed it to an unsigned int so no negative numbers.But It's still not that safe, It can easily overflow the stack, if someone make a 100000 x 100000 it will use 10000000000 x 4 bytes. Which should overflow the stack. This answer was meant to show V:LA not safe coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use **pointers to pointers/double pointers** (`**`). For a n-D array you repeat the process of dynamic allocation (`malloc`) **n** times in a loop and reference each with a pointer to newly the allocated array. The only issue is that the last array does not use double pointers, so your runtime code has to know when to use values instead of double-pointers at the last dimension. Using this you can still do setting/getting via conventional syntax like `M[1][2][3][1] = 5;` (mind that 0 is the first element!).

Also make sure to **initialize** your values.

For a good example and treatise of double array pointers check 'The C Progamming Language' from Kerningham/Richie, which is readily available online.

Note: there are other elegant and not so elegant solutions to this. For example using macros/metaprogramming to write the allocation code at compile time and pass an `define` option (`-DDIMS=4`) or nest-able data structures representing arrays like trees (check classic data structure literature for multi-dim arrays.)

Comment: (a) C has variable-length arrays, which do permit creation of arrays whose size is given at run-time. (b) The question appears to ask for an array with a variable number of dimensions, not an array with a variable size of dimension.

Comment: @Eric: thank you for your comments. I was indeed off the question of the OP. Also removed code, as imho OP should exercise this on her own, given a hint.